# Will `/scoreboard players tag` remove tags from ineligible players/entities that were previously tagged?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say I put the following command, which is used as an example in the [15w32b wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/15w32b), in a repeating command block and set it to run:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add InAir {OnGround:0b}
```

Anyone who is not on the ground will get the `InAir` tag, but will the tag automatically be removed when they hit the ground?  If the tag is not removed automatically, how do I remove them?  The linked article doesn't seem to provide a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the tag won't be removed automatically.  You can test this yourself by placing the following command in your command block chain:

```
/tell @p[tag=InAir] Jumping
```

After jumping the first time, you will continuously receive the "Jumping" message, even after you return to the ground.

What you need to do, similar to what you've done in the past with scoreboard objectives used in boolean tests, is clear the tags of everyone before reapplying them to those you want tagged.  In your example, you'd use the following command:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a remove InAir
```

which is the obvious counterpart to the the `add` version of the command, but that's not stated in the wiki.

I should note that I haven't tested to see if the `remove` version also accepts the data tag, but I suspect it does.  That would allow for some interesting logic.

Comment: Yes, the `remove` version does accept the data tag, so you can use `/scor...ag @a remove InAir {OnGround:1b}`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this command:
/scoreboard players tag @a remove InAir {OnGround:1b}

This command will remove the tag from anyone who is one the ground {OnGround:1b}

Obviously, You should make sure the command blocks are set to always-active and repeating on both commands: Mine and Yours